# Parsing drug name

Tags: string, parsing

I am trying to write to parse medication names that have the following structure

```
Ingredient 1/ Ingredient 2/ Ingredient 3/..../Ingredient N Strength 1 - Strength 2 - Strength 3 - ... - Strength N Dosage Form Quantity, UOM
```

For Example, consider the following medication names

```
Ampicillin Sodium / Sodium Chloride / Sulbactam Sodium 2 g/100 mL-0.9%-1 g/100 mL Solution for injection, 100 mL
```

It would be parsed to the following:

```
Ingredient 1: Ampicillin Sodium
Concentration 1: 2g/100 mL

Ingredient 2: Sodium Chloride
Concentration 2: 0.9%

Ingredient 3: Sulbactam Sodium
Concentration 3: 1g/100 mL

Dosage form: Solution for Injection
Quantity: 100 mL
```

I try to write a regex to parse the medication name but it proved to be challenging.

I would appreciate your help in this manner

Comment: What regex tool/programming language are you using?

Comment: I am using R as my primary programming language

Comment: Can you use another language (like Python) for this? If so, can you post a few more examples of medications? It would help in order to test the answer.